# i want to set order for 2 functions

Tags: javascript, function, cryptocurrency

my problem is it allway run addtoken first then switchnetwork even when i change their location. Is there anyway to set in order these funtion. I want switchnetwork fisrt then addtoken laler .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
        async function switchChain()
        {  
            const chainParams = 
            {
                'BNB' : 
                {
                chainId: '0x38',
                chainName: 'Smart Chain',
                nativeCurrency: {
                name: 'Binance Coin',
                symbol: 'BNB',
                decimals: 18
                },
            rpcUrls: ['https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'],
            blockExplorerUrls: ['https://bscscan.com']
            }
        }
        
        // Get metamask on the right network
            const switchToChain = (chainName) => 
            {
                window.ethereum.request
                (
                    {
                    method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
                    params: [chainParams[chainName]]
                    }
                )
            }  
        
        let desiredChain = 'BNB'
        switchToChain(desiredChain)
          
        }

        async function addToken() {
        const tokenAddress = '0xef50c139be0b67baab4f834d3d9a1f09d2691e02'; // replace with your own crypto address
        const tokenSymbol = 'SGC'; // replace with your own crypto symbol
        const tokenDecimals = 18; // put number of deciimals
        const tokenImage = 'https://i.imgur.com/o2EXAlM.png'; // add link to a token image
        try 
            {
            const wasAdded = await ethereum.request(
                {
                method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
                params: 
                    {
                    type: 'ERC20', 
                    options: {
                    address: tokenAddress, 
                    symbol: tokenSymbol, 
                    decimals: tokenDecimals, 
                    image: tokenImage, 
                    },
                    },
                });
        
                if (wasAdded) {
                console.log('Currency Added Successfuly');
                } else {
                console.log('The currency has not been added');
                }
            } 
            catch (error) 
            {
            console.log(error);
            }
            
        }
        
        </script>
<button onclick="switchChain(); addToken();">Add Token to MetaMask</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the function call to addToken() from the button and call addToken() from the end of switchChain().  Let me know if that works.  When you call a async function it goes on and executes the rest of your code while waiting for a response. It would appear that switchChain() takes longer to execute then addToken().  You can also look into using **await**

```js
async function switchChain()
        {  
            const chainParams = 
            {
                'BNB' : 
                {
                chainId: '0x38',
                chainName: 'Smart Chain',
                nativeCurrency: {
                name: 'Binance Coin',
                symbol: 'BNB',
                decimals: 18
                },
            rpcUrls: ['https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'],
            blockExplorerUrls: ['https://bscscan.com']
            }
        }
        
        // Get metamask on the right network
            const switchToChain = (chainName) => 
            {
                await window.ethereum.request
                (
                    {
                    method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
                    params: [chainParams[chainName]]
                    }
                )
            }  
        
        let desiredChain = 'BNB'
        switchToChain(desiredChain)
          
        }

        async function addToken() {
        const tokenAddress = '0xef50c139be0b67baab4f834d3d9a1f09d2691e02'; // replace with your own crypto address
        const tokenSymbol = 'SGC'; // replace with your own crypto symbol
        const tokenDecimals = 18; // put number of deciimals
        const tokenImage = 'https://i.imgur.com/o2EXAlM.png'; // add link to a token image
        try 
            {
            const wasAdded = await ethereum.request(
                {
                method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
                params: 
                    {
                    type: 'ERC20', 
                    options: {
                    address: tokenAddress, 
                    symbol: tokenSymbol, 
                    decimals: tokenDecimals, 
                    image: tokenImage, 
                    },
                    },
                });
        
                if (wasAdded) {
                console.log('Currency Added Successfuly');
                } else {
                console.log('The currency has not been added');
                }
            } 
            catch (error) 
            {
            console.log(error);
            }
            
            addToken();
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="switchChain(); ">Add Token to MetaMask</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still the same mate

Comment: add this to your switch function:   await window.ethereum.request